# True or False: There is no way to set the file owner of a cell loaded using registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

In my View Controller I am registering a nib using

```
 [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCellReuseIdentifier"];
```

In the cell's nib I have used the same identifier as above.

The problem I have is that although I am able to wire a valueChanged event (for a control in my custom cell) to my View Controller I get a `NSInvalidArgumentException, unrecognized selector sent to instance` when interacting with the control.

Are you aware of a way to programatically check if the file owner got set after the  `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` call in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` call?

Cheers, Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it. You are trying to use a xib file to define a cell for use in a storyboard table, and link things to the view controller, and you have the cell in a xib because you use it in several tables, yes?

The only way around this is have found is to create a property on the cell subclass to represent the view controller, and set this to the view controller when the cell is dequeued. It's a bit clumsy and in the end I moved a lot of my code into the cell itself, and just passed the whole model object over to the cell instead. It worked pretty well and felt like a much cleaner design.

Comment: I am using a table view controller (no storyboarding) but I am registering the cell in `viewDidLoad:`. I solved the problem in the end by simply adding a target on my cell's control inside the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` when there were no associated targets already (thus it's only done once). I then use the tag to identify the indexPath.